# Is there a risk to returning early from a lambda function while API requests are still running?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, async-await

I have a nodeJS lambda function where I want to start 3 API calls immediately, but I receive an unknown number of items back from each API call, and I don't know how long each API call will take to execute. I have a specific priority of the items, so if the the first API call returns enough items, I don't care about the other 2 API calls.

I could just wait until the first one resolves to decide if I want to kick off the 2nd and 3rd API calls, but I like the idea of the calls being run in parallel and only awaiting them if required.

Is there anything wrong with starting all 3 API calls immediately and just returning early if I no longer care about the results of the other 2?

```js
  const getFiveThings = async () => {
    const things = [];
    const redThingsPromise = getRedThings();
    const greenThingsPromise = getGreenThings();
    const blueThingsPromise = getBlueThings();

    const redThings = await redThingsPromise;
    things.push(...redThings);
    if (things.length >= 5) {
      return things;
    }

    const greenThings = await greenThingsPromise;
    things.push(...greenThings);
    if (things.length >= 5) {
      return things;
    }

    const blueThings = await blueThingsPromise;
    things.push(...blueThings);
    return things;
  };
```

Comment: what do you mean of `unknown` items?

Comment: I have a specific number of items that I need (in the contrived example code, I went with five). Each API call returns some number of items, could be 0, could be 100. I accumulate them after each call, and if I've reached the required number of items, I can return early.

Comment: You said but I receive an unknown items back from each API call, so what do you mean exactly from uknown? the item type or the number of items that you desired?

Comment: Ah I see your question. I know what I will be getting back, just not how many of them.

Comment: No, not really, other than potentially sending unnecessary requests to the server.

Comment: Does the order matter? I.e. do you want the blue items first, and only add the green ones if there aren't enough blue ones?

Comment: Yep order matters. If there are enough red ones alone, I don't care about blue or green. If there aren't enough red ones, fill in with blues. If red + blue still isn't enough, fill in with greens.

Comment: @mitchelc I think the only thing to consider is that once your handler returns, the execution environment of your lambda instance is "frozen". If another event then comes in within a short enough time, the environment will be "thawed" and reused. At that point, code which may not have completed (e.g. an async request) may then resume executing.

Comment: Depending on what and how much that code does, and especially in your case, it probably won't cause any issues/interference with the current execution. But if it for example logs stuff to the console, you may see output from a previous invocation mixed with output from the current invocation (in cloudwatch).

Answer (score 0):

IF you are 100% certain that you can end without the others, then no. Those responses come back from the api's you called but just disappear into the void. I use this on a project where we are about 3x faster than the existing legacy system. We make two asyncronious calls - one to the legacy via its api, one to the new system. which ever one is returned first is returned to the API, and the other async thread is cancelled.

We have some logic in there that if our new system returns an error, then it will NOT cancel the other thread and go ahead and wait for the legacy system as a failsafe during rollout.

The API responses are not handshake responses - they simply are sent back to the requestor - if they are no longer listening, then it falls on deaf ears as it were.